# What are accelerators in C# and how do I use them?

Tags: c#, winforms, accelerator

In my online course I'm asked to put a label (`lblQuestion` with accelerator) and ComboBox on a form.

Putting a label and a combo box on a form is simple enough in VS 2010, but I am not sure what an accelerator is and how I use it?

Comment: Not sure, can you provide some context? Could your professor be asking you to use these: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/accelerator/?

Comment: I assume he means underlined letters for accessibility (`Alt` + _x_)

Comment: SimpleCoder: I'm afraid what I initially wrote is all that is stated in that part of the question. I'll take a look at the link you provided, thanks

Comment: SLaks: I think that is what he means. So do I go to Tools menu than to External Tools for that?

Comment: Thanks for the help SimpleCoder and SLaks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For setting an accelerator you will use & character in front of the letter of your label, that you need to make available as an accelerator. See here: http://blog.csharphelper.com/2012/05/30/use-accelerators-on-labels-and-buttons-in-c.aspx for more details.

Comment: Oh right so it would be &Quesion in the text box right?

Comment: @Kiviuq Yes, that should make ALT+Q change focus to Quesion.